# How do I handle custom 404 page using python

Tags: python, url, request, http-status-code-404

```
In[50]: requests.get("http://outage-outsourcing.oracle.com/")
Out[50]: <Response [200]>
```

The url in above gives message as "This application is currently unavailable. We apologize for the inconvenience.". It should return status code 404 as the page is not working, how can I handle such cases where custom error page is defined.

Answer (score 1):

It's upto them what http status code they send.You can not do anything about it.
You may define your own criteria to identify them.
for e.g. You may search through response for error message to identify them.

Comment: So basically, for every custom page we need to define criteria? Or is there any thing that these URLs won't contain some headers than others?